# How to switch the image based on the selected gender in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Im very new to angularjs.what im trying to do is just to assign differnt images to a user based on the selected gender(took the value from the textfield.),ie 
if gender==male{
male image.
}
else{
female image.
}

im just saving the text from the text field into an array,

saving code:

```
$scope.save = function () {
            var contact = {'name':$scope.name,'phone':$scope.phone,'email':$scope.email,'gender':$scope.gender};
            var arrayOfObject = [];
            if (localStorage.getItem('data') == null || localStorage.getItem('data') == '') {
                arrayOfObject.push(contact);
            }
            else {
                arrayOfObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
                arrayOfObject.push(contact);
            }

        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(arrayOfObject));
        console.log('array is:',localStorage);

  }
```

retrieving code:

```
var completeList = [];
    $scope.completeList = myService.getData();

    if($scope.completeList!==null && $scope.completeList!==0){


    for(var i=0; i <$scope.completeList.length; i++)
    {

        $scope.gender = $scope.completeList[i].gender;

        if($scope.gender == "female"){
         $scope.image1= 'images/female.jpg';
        }
        else{
        $scope.image1 = 'images/profile.png';
        }
        console.log($scope.image1);
    }
```

in html page

```
<tr ng-repeat="n in completeList| filter:search">
          <td ng-click="detailView($index)">
             <div><img width="100px" height="50px"  ng-src="{{image1}}" ></div>
```

But the problem is html is only dispalying the image i saved lastly into the array(ie if i save last object as "male",it is dispalying only males images by replacing all the female images and vice-versa..

Can anyone please help me where im going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.gender can only hold one value at once.

Inside your `for` loop, you should do something like :

```
$scope.completeList[i].gender_image = $scope.completeList[i].gender == "female" ? 'images/female.jpg' : 'images/profile.jpg'
```

And then in your template :

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in completeList| filter:search">
  <td ng-click="detailView($index)">
    <div><img width="100px" height="50px"  ng-src="{{user.gender_image}}" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove you `if($scope.gender == "female"){....` code from controller and try this in your HTML template

```
<tr ng-repeat="n in completeList| filter:search">
  <td ng-click="detailView($index)">
     <div ng-init="genderImage = n.gender == "female" ? 'images/female.jpg' : 'images/profile.jpg'">
        <img src="images/female.jpg" ng-src="{{genderImage}}" />
     </div>
```

Comment: <div>
   <img width="100px" height="50px"  src="images/female.jpg" ng-if="n==='female'" >
   <img width="100px" height="50px"  src="images/profile.png" ng-if="n==='male'" >
   </div>  when i did like this it is displaying both images :(

Comment: @suji, that my mistake use `ng-if="n.gender===` I missed `.gender`